# Toad for oracle - open automatically generated script

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a script generator in .bat file. This .bat generates a sql script and saves it on disk. 
Is there any option to open automatically this script in toad? Also if there is already toad application running to open this script in running toad instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the filename to Toad as a command line argument.

Example: `>Toad.exe "C:\My Scripts\MyFile.sql"`

On the Startup page in Toad's Options there is an option to only allow multiple instances of Toad. If that is unchecked the above call will reuse an open instance of Toad and open your script.